# Windows 8 upgrade Recovery Disk

Tags: windows-8, system-recovery, system-repair-disc

I have upgraded to Windows 8 from Win 7. I want to create a recovery disk for Windows 8, just in case something goes wrong. I didn't find the option of creating it from the control panel.

How do I create a Recovery CD/DVD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not find a direct way to create a disc. If you do not have a flash drive in your computer however, the Recovery Drive wizard will prompt you to create a disc instead.

Start by opening the Search panel. Make sure to select Settings, search for "Recovery", then select `Create a recovery drive`
[image: Recovery1]

The rest is pretty much a click-through. If you want to make a disc instead of a USB, make sure you don't have any removable media inserted. It seems you can also create a copy of the OEM restore now!
[image: Recovery2]

Comment: Yep, this is what I did, and what the link in Jared's post suggests. Hope, that USB drive helps me in the future.

Comment: You should know that not all USB drives are bootable... (I have had very bad look with PNY in particular) so you might want to make sure you can boot your USB drive before the time comes where you might need it...

Comment: @KumarBibek Wasn't trying to steal his thunder, but typically link only posts are frowned upon on Super User. Links can go dead, and leading users around can feel tedious. It's typically better to provide a short description of the link.

Comment: No worries about stolen thunder here. Its not a competition.... oh wait....

Comment: @JaredTritsch I'll bump you up to the 3 point mark anyway. =D

Comment: @r.tanner.f TYVM. Please accept his answer. It's better.

Answer (score 2):

It is done by creating recovery USB drives. Like so:

http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-tip-create-recovery-media-144098

Comment: This seems a more reliable way. Trying this.

Comment: @Aierou - Why would that be?

Comment: -1: Link-only answers are considered a no-no due to possible future link rot.  Please include pertinent information in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another method to create a system repair disc is to search using "recdisc"

.

[image]

then click recdisc.exe to run.

or if you are at the desktop use the run command "recdisc.exe" (no quotes).

.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Simply follow this tutorial: [link](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-create-windows-8-recovery-cd/) and you should be just fine.

Comment: But this says its a "Windows 7 File Recovery". Does it actually create a win 8 recovery disc?

Comment: That's only a goof on Microsoft's end. Ignore it 
Edit: what I mean is that's what the file is called. It still creates a Windows 8 recovery disk.

Comment: It's really hard to believe that it's a goof up. The descriptions just mention Windows everywhere, so, I am a bit sceptic. If ever, I get into that situation, I don't want to boot into Win7 and upgrade to Win8 yet again.

Comment: @KumarBibek There is no way you would be able to create a Windows 7 disk using the application unless you were running Windows 7. The application simply packages the image of your current operating system with a setup dialog. So without Windows 7 installed, it would not be able to package it.

Comment: @Aierou Those instructions do not work in RTM, searching "Windows 7 file recovery" returns No apps match your search"

Comment: -1: Link-only answers are considered a no-no due to possible future link rot.  Please include pertinent information in your answer.

Comment: @techie007 Thanks for your input on this year-old answer; may it forever remain inane.