# Windows 8 - Possible to create a system image?

Tags: backup, windows-8

In Windows 7 you could create a system image that you restore later on in the Backup and Restore options:

[image]

However Backup and Restore options have changed in Windows 8. They look like this now:

[image]

Is it still possible to create a system image so that I can restore it later on or has this 
feature been removed?

Comment: Also might want to take a look at [this](http://superuser.com/questions/493563/windows-8-upgrade-recovery-disk).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows Backup has been renamed to Windows 7 File Recovery.

Click Control Panel, Windows 7 File Recovery, Create System Image.

[image: Windows 7 File Recovery]

Comment: ... Thats a rather silly thing to call it...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Yes; I have no idea why they did that.

Comment: Another interesting way to make a backup image to be used with "Refresh"...http://www.extremetech.com/computing/134611-how-to-reinstall-windows-8-without-losing-your-files-and-programs

Comment: I've made images with the Win7 File Recovery's tool. But the boot CD never EVER finds them on the USB drive. Maddening.

Comment: The name was to explicitly indicate that this was a [deprecated feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx "Windows 7 Backup and Restore deprecated"), and it's been removed from Win8.1 (doesn't seem to be available in the Preview at least).

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 8.1 the `Windows 7 File Recovery` Feature is removed, but you can use the `System Image Backup` instead.

Follow the Link for further informations:
http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/windows-81-tip-use-system-image-backup

HowToGeek.com listed some features which are removed in Windows 8.1
http://www.howtogeek.com/167610/8-features-microsoft-removed-in-windows-8.1/

Comment: Instead of just providing links, incorporate some of the information @ the links in the answer here. Links don't always last forever.