# How can I make a DVD bootable Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, bootable-media

I've bought a computer with Windows 8 pre-installed. I don't want Windows , so I intend to format and install Linux. But I don't have any Windows 8 CD/DVD that I'd like to keep . How can I make a usable copy out of my current system in a CD/DVD ?

Comment: If you contact the OEM they can provide you a recovery media disk.  There should also be software installed already to do this.  Additional a Windows Recovery Disk is helpful to have.  Its also easier to get a Windows 8.1 .iso directly from Microsoft then it is to get a Windows 8.0 .iso image.

Comment: The availability of a hard copy of the system mainly depends on your computer vendor and the agreement done with Microsoft, in some cases you can download the ISO of the system, in other cases you have to buy it separately.What kind of computer have you?

Have you done some search on the net? There are a lot of suggestions (for example [here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/4098-73-save-installed-laptop-future) or [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/pre-installed-windows-8-product-key-and-backup/c154efc8-fa92-48a2-b673-2f75062a3560)).

Comment: It is an Acer Aspire MC605.

Comment: @techie007 - While the question is indeed similar most of those answers in the possible duplicate would not apply to a system that no longer had Windows installed.  A `Windows Recovery Media` created by Windows would only allow you to repair a Windows installation not install it after it was removed.

Comment: @Ramhound I see what you're saying.  Perhaps this is a better match: [Windows 8 - Possible to create a system image?](http://superuser.com/questions/494382/windows-8-possible-to-create-a-system-image?lq=1)

Comment: @techie007 - I would agree thats close enough to be at least considered.  Although I am not sure if the media created by that feature would actually reinstall Windows.

Comment: Here's a 8.1 guide from MS: [Create installation media for Windows 8.1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media), and here's a win 8 one from WinSuperSite: [Windows 8 Tip: Create Setup Media After Using the Web Installer](http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/windows-8-tip-create-setup-media-after-using-web-installer) - Bascially run the Web installer, and choose to make media - I have no idea if/how this will work if the user has an OEM install/key. :)

Comment: Have you considered to make a dual boot?

Comment: @PaoloGibellini - Yes. But I'm not interested in it.

Answer (score 0):

I use Acronis and highly recommend it! It is simple to backup your OS and restore whenever you want.

Comment: Well, I'll not pay for a default Windows copy on-line. All I see are non free subscriptions, and free trial subscriptions for 30 days period. I wanted just to store for undefined period.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Acronis answer was unacceptable because it was paid or 30 day trial software, consider using [EASEUS ToDo Backup Free Edition](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/easeus_todo_backup_free_edition.html). It allows you to make a complete system image from within Windows (while it runs..., no need to restart. Uses Volume Shadow Copy Service, real neat) and allows you to make an emergency boot disc that lets you restore from your image backup when disaster strikes.